# Number of key-value pair in reducer

Tags: hadoop

My question is:

In hadoop mapreduce, for each intermediate key, each reducer task can emit, only one final key-value pair per key. Or as many as programmer wants?

Comment: Many as programmer wants. You may do, for example:

context.write(key,value1)
context.write(key,value2)
.....
context.write(key,valuen)

Answer (score 1):

Two points here:

1. Reducer can emit many key-value pairs
2. All keys are of same type and values have the same type.

for example,

public static class Reduce extends Reducer {

contex.write(new Text("key1"), new LongWritable(4));

conte.write(new LongWritable(1), new Text("value"));  -- this lines gives you a compile time error.

Keys must be of Text type and Value must be of LongWritable type.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your key is a LongWritable and the values are Text. Then in the reducer you expect to get many Text values for the same key, and probably you want to write each of these value in a line:

```
for (Text value : values) {

    context.write(key,value)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As many as the programmer wants, the only constraint is the type of all the keys and values should be same. MapReduce doesn't restricts you use the keys and values as such as long as you are using Writables
so for a particular key

```
 for (Text value : values) {
    context.write(key,value)
 }
```

and

```
 for(int i=0; i < 10000 ; i++){
    context.write(key, new Text(String.valueOf(i)));
  //context.write(new Text("MyRandomKey"), new Text(String.valueOf(i)));
 }
```

both of these are fine considering you have defined your keys and values as text in reducer